# rsync: read list of files from pipe

Tags: find, rsync, pipe, file-transfer

I can transfer file `/tmp/file` using `rsync` to remote server:

```
rsync -R -av /tmp/file root@server:/
```

but how can I provide the list of files to be transfert from a pipe? I tried using the `--files-from=` option with `/dev/stdin`, but that does not work:

```
echo /tmp/file | rsync -R -av --files-from=/dev/stdin root@server:/
```

(neither does it work with regular file)

Hoe can I make rsync read from pipe, so that I can use output of find, for example?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the error message. Also you seem to have forgotten the source argument in the invocation of `rsync`.

Comment: If you know what will be there, you may use `--exclude=file1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to specify both source and target arguments to `rsync`, even when you're reading pathnames from a file:

```bsh
echo /tmp/file | rsync -av --files-from=- / user@server:/
```

The pathnames read by `rsync` would be relative to the `/` source directory.  The `-R` option is implied when using `--files-from`, and standard input may be specified with `-`.

See also

- `man rsync`
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

You may want to ask a separate question about your intention to pass output from `find` to `rsync` using `--from-file`.  There is probably a much safer way of doing what you intend to do.  For example, you may want to use `-print0` with `find` and pair that up with `-from0` with `rsync`.  See the manuals for `rsync` and `find` on your system.

Comment: but what do you intend to process with -print0 and -from0? filenames having linebreak characters?

Comment: @Mary Yes. Filenames containing newlines are valid on Unix, so listing them in a text file is problematic.

Comment: I also noticed, there's an explanation about -print0 in find manpage (indeed - possible newlines in filenames...)

Comment: Note the stray `/` in the middle: `--files-from=- / user@server:/` — I missed initially. Also `user@server:/` can of course be replaced with a local path.

Answer (score 0):

You could use -exec option together with find:

```
find -type f -name /tmp/file -exec rsync -R -av {} root@server:/ \;
```

The {} is the result from previous result, everything found before -exec.
; is indication the end of exec